# Crosstab of row - SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to generate a matrix or crosstab with the rows below:

```
TBL_CURRENCY_PAIR
ID | ISO_1 | ISO_2
 1 | EUR   | USD 
 2 | JPY   | USD
 4 | GBP   | USD
```

I'd like to obtain a oracle view that contains something like below:

```
VIEW_PAIR
|PAIR|
USD.USD
GBP.USD
EUR.USD
JPY.USD
USD.GBP
GBP.GBP
EUR.GBP
JPY.GBP
USD.EUR
GBP.EUR
EUR.EUR
JPY.EUR
USD.JPY
GBP.JPY
EUR.JPY
JPY.JPY
```

I have tried with inner join to obtain a recursivity but nothing...

thanks in advance for your help,
Have nice day.

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  You have the three rows and you want all the rows in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following does what you want:

```
with c as (
      select iso_1 as iso
      from tbl_currency_pair
      union
      select iso_2
      from tbl_currency_pair
     )
select c1.iso || '.' || c2.iso
from c c1 cross join c c2;
```

This generates all unique combinations of the currencies in the pair table.